# Webform in subfolder using master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Currently all of my web-form files (.aspx) are in root folder of my project (VS 2012).

I created a new folder name "**pages**" and add a new webform to it (WebForm1), using master page. When I run this page, its address is localhost:49217/pages/WebForm1.aspx which is correct, problems are:

- All of links now have been added the word "**pages**", for example the correct link should be localhost:49217/Contact.aspx now became: localhost:49217/**pages**/Contact.aspx
- The CSS look weird, kind of missing some css files (the path is wrong).

The CSS code in master page, css files are in **css** folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

If I add a new webform in root folder, everything is fine, but if I do that in a subfolder, everything is messed up.

**EDIT:**

1. CSS has been fixed, thanks for everybody.
2. Still the "**pages**" not fixed, it is added in all the links (of the master page)

Comment: Show us where you reference CSS file in your master page.

Comment: @IrishChieftain: I added into the question, is that what you need?

Comment: I agree with LilBiggs02 that this is normal to have the pages added to the URL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When referencing style sheets or java script files inside of a master page I usually do the following:

```
<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/reset.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/master.js") %>'></script>
```

This will work if you are debugging on your local, deploying to a web server in a virtual directory or if you deploy to the website root.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions. Can you help me with the "pages" part, it has been added to all the links (of the master)

Comment: Please try the above code. It will work if you move the child pages into a different sub folder.

Comment: Tried your code, it fixed the CSS but the the links still being added "pages" onto it. For example all of my link on the menu of master page (Product | Service | Contact ...) became: .../pages/product or .../pages/contact

Comment: @RonaldinhoState - This is how asp.net works. The url maps to the specific file location. Since product is in the pages sub folder this is why you see the url. If you want to change the url check out asp.net routing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX

Answer (score 6):

Your paths are relative to the current directory, you need to prefix them with a slash so that they always reference the root directory. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

You'll also have to do the same thing to your image paths.

Comment: OK now CSS looks ok now but the "pages" still being added to all the links. Do you have any ideas?